# How should Type II SS be calculated in a mixed model?

Tags: r, anova, mixed-model, sums-of-squares

I have a data set (and corresponding mixed model) which gets very different p-values for one of the two-way interactions when tested using Type I (sequential, taking care that it's last), and Type II (using `lmerTest` and `car` packages).

The sequential and `car` packages "agree" and the `lmerTest` package is different.

What are these methods doing, why are they different, and which is "right"?

*(Note that there are many questions about Type I/II/III here, but none that I see that answer this specific question about Type II. Also, while I'm using R, and am interested in the particular implementations used in R, the bigger question is statistical, not about the coding.)*

```
library(lme4)
library(lmerTest)
library(car)

d <- data.frame(
  Y = c(6, 4, 5, 7, 6, 8, 9, 0, 10, 9, 10, 8, 7, 7, 6, 5, 6, 7, 8, 
        7, 9, 10, 10, 6, 5, 8, 10, 4, 6, 7, 7, 10, 6, 10, 10, 7, 6, 3, 
        6, 7, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11, 10, 7, 8, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 5, 4, 8, 8, 8, 
        7, 9, 5, 4, 4, 6, 5, 7, 8, 3, 9, 8, 8, 7, 5, 7, 4, 5, 5, 4, 6, 
        8, 8, 6, 7, 8, 4, 2, 4, 4, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 8, 7, 6, 4, 2, 3, 3, 
        3, 0, 1, 4, 6, 4, 2, 0, 9, 9, 10, 8, 10, 9, 7, 9, 6, 5, 9, 7, 
        6, 2, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 9, 8, 7, 8, 1, 0, 3, 2, 2, 5, 3, 5, 8, 
        6, 6, 6, 8, 6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 6, 7, 8, 3, 3),
  A = rep(c(2, 5, 4, 4, 2, 3, 3, 5, 9, 3, 7, 2, 11), each=12),
  B = factor(rep(1:2, each=6)),
  C = factor(1:6),
  ID = factor(rep(1:13, each=12))
)
options(contrasts=c("contr.sum","contr.poly")) # for Type III car::Anova
```

Here's my model, I'm noticing the differences for the B:C interaction.

```
m1 <- lmer(Y ~ A * B * C + (1|ID), data=d)
```

Type I Anova (from `lmerTest`), with B:C interaction last except for A:B:C, gives p=0.04 for B:C. (However, order doesn't seem to matter.)

```
anova(m1, type=1, ddf="Kenward-Roger")
#> Analysis of Variance Table of type I  with  Kenward-Roger 
#> approximation for degrees of freedom
#>        Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF DenDF F.value    Pr(>F)    
#> A       8.794   8.794     1    11   2.908   0.11621    
#> B     136.641 136.641     1   121  45.178 6.269e-10 ***
#> C      14.128   2.826     5   121   0.934   0.46141    
#> A:B     0.381   0.381     1   121   0.126   0.72330    
#> A:C    45.874   9.175     5   121   3.034   0.01291 *  
#> B:C    34.821   6.964     5   121   2.303   0.04882 *  
#> A:B:C  21.860   4.372     5   121   1.446   0.21285
```

Type II Anova from the `car` package gives the same results.

```
Anova(m1, type=2, test="F")
#> Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II Wald F tests with Kenward-Roger df)
#> 
#> Response: Y
#>             F Df Df.res    Pr(>F)    
#> A      2.9075  1     11   0.11621    
#> B     45.1784  1    121 6.269e-10 ***
#> C      0.9343  5    121   0.46141    
#> A:B    0.1259  1    121   0.72330    
#> A:C    3.0335  5    121   0.01291 *  
#> B:C    2.3026  5    121   0.04882 *  
#> A:B:C  1.4456  5    121   0.21285
```

Type II Anova from `lmerTest`, gives p=0.88 for B:C, and is identical with Type III in both `lmerTest` and `car`.

```
anova(m1, type=2, ddf="Kenward-Roger")
#> Analysis of Variance Table of type II  with  Kenward-Roger 
#> approximation for degrees of freedom
#>       Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF DenDF F.value    Pr(>F)    
#> A      8.794   8.794     1    11  2.9075 0.1162113    
#> B     41.500  41.500     1   121 13.7214 0.0003209 ***
#> C     50.879  10.176     5   121  3.3645 0.0070072 ** 
#> A:B    0.381   0.381     1   121  0.1259 0.7233027    
#> A:C   45.874   9.175     5   121  3.0335 0.0129149 *  
#> B:C    5.174   1.035     5   121  0.3422 0.8864025    
#> A:B:C 21.860   4.372     5   121  1.4456 0.2128521   

Anova(m1, type=3, test="F")
#> Analysis of Deviance Table (Type III Wald F tests with Kenward-Roger df)
#> 
#> Response: Y
#>                   F Df Df.res    Pr(>F)    
#> (Intercept) 88.2434  1     11 1.376e-06 ***
#> A            2.9075  1     11 0.1162113    
#> B           13.7214  1    121 0.0003209 ***
#> C            3.3645  5    121 0.0070072 ** 
#> A:B          0.1259  1    121 0.7233027    
#> A:C          3.0335  5    121 0.0129149 *  
#> B:C          0.3422  5    121 0.8864025    
#> A:B:C        1.4456  5    121 0.2128521    

anova(m1, type=3, ddf="Kenward-Roger")
#> Analysis of Variance Table of type III  with  Kenward-Roger 
#> approximation for degrees of freedom
#>       Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF DenDF F.value    Pr(>F)    
#> A      8.794   8.794     1    11  2.9075 0.1162113    
#> B     41.500  41.500     1   121 13.7214 0.0003209 ***
#> C     50.879  10.176     5   121  3.3645 0.0070072 ** 
#> A:B    0.381   0.381     1   121  0.1259 0.7233027    
#> A:C   45.874   9.175     5   121  3.0335 0.0129149 *  
#> B:C    5.174   1.035     5   121  0.3422 0.8864025    
#> A:B:C 21.860   4.372     5   121  1.4456 0.2128521
```

Comment: I just figured it out (partially)... Funny how posting in public can do that. :) I'll post what I found out as an answer but if others have a fuller explanation, please answer as well!

Comment: For a more direct comparison, use Kenward-Roger ddf approximations, which both packages support, instead of comparing the "infinite" ddf (Chisq) with the Satterthwaite ddf.

Comment: @Livius, done..

Answer (score 5):

The difference between the Type II tests from `car::Anova` and the `anova` method for lmerTest is due to how continuous explanatory variables are handled. The first passus in the Details section of `help(Anova)` describes how `Anova` handles them:

> The designations "type-II" and "type-III" are borrowed from SAS, but
>   the definitions used here do not correspond precisely to those
>   employed by SAS. Type-II tests are calculated according to the
>   principle of marginality, testing each term after all others, except
>   ignoring the term's higher-order relatives; so-called type-III tests
>   violate marginality, testing each term in the model after all of the
>   others. This definition of Type-II tests corresponds to the tests
>   produced by SAS for analysis-of-variance models, where all of the
>   predictors are factors, but not more generally (i.e., when there are
>   quantitative predictors). Be very careful in formulating the model for
>   type-III tests, or the hypotheses tested will not make sense.

so while lmerTest implements the SAS definition of Type II as described [in this paper](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v082i13), `car::Anova` does something different. The SAS definition is described [here](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statugestimable/61763/PDF/default/statugestimable.pdf) which mean that a test for a term is marginal to all terms that it is not contained in. The definition of *containment* is given in the SAS document as:

Given two effects `F1` and `F2`, `F1` is said to be contained in `F2` provided that the following two conditions are met:

- Both effects involve the same continuous variables (if any).
- `F2` has more CLASS [factors in R] variables than `F1` does, and if `F1` has CLASS variables, they all appear in `F2`

So in your model `B:C` is not contained in `A:B:C` because `A` is continuous and the type II hypothesis of `B:C` is therefore marginal to `A:B:C`. `car::Anova` does not distinguish between factors and covariates in this context so if `A` was a factor `car::Anova` and lmerTest-`anova` agrees:

```
d$A2 <- cut(d$A, quantile(d$A), include.lowest = TRUE)
m2 <- lmer(Y ~ A2 * B * C + (1|ID), data=d)
anova(m2, type=2, ddf="Ken") 
Type II Analysis of Variance Table with Kenward-Roger's method
        Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF DenDF F value    Pr(>F)    
A2      17.210   5.737     3     9  1.7035   0.23533    
B      136.641 136.641     1    99 40.5756 5.987e-09 ***
C       14.128   2.826     5    99  0.8391   0.52512    
A2:B    11.137   3.712     3    99  1.1024   0.35193    
A2:C    38.816   2.588    15    99  0.7684   0.70879    
B:C     34.821   6.964     5    99  2.0680   0.07575 .  
A2:B:C  50.735   3.382    15    99  1.0044   0.45709    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
Anova(m2, type=2, test="F")
Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II Wald F tests with Kenward-Roger df)

Response: Y
             F Df Df.res    Pr(>F)    
A2      1.7035  3      9   0.23533    
B      40.5756  1     99 5.987e-09 ***
C       0.8391  5     99   0.52512    
A2:B    1.1024  3     99   0.35193    
A2:C    0.7684 15     99   0.70879    
B:C     2.0680  5     99   0.07575 .  
A2:B:C  1.0044 15     99   0.45709    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

The `lmerTest::show_tests()` function can be used to see exactly which linear function of the model coefficients makes up the tested hypothesis. For example, we have that

```
show_tests(anova(m1, type=2))$`B:C`
      (Intercept) A B1 C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 A:B1 A:C1 A:C2 A:C3 A:C4 A:C5 B1:C1 B1:C2 B1:C3
B1:C1           0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0    0    0    0    0    0    0     1     0     0
B1:C2           0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     1     0
B1:C3           0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     1
B1:C4           0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0
B1:C5           0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0
      B1:C4 B1:C5 A:B1:C1 A:B1:C2 A:B1:C3 A:B1:C4 A:B1:C5
B1:C1     0     0       0       0       0       0       0
B1:C2     0     0       0       0       0       0       0
B1:C3     0     0       0       0       0       0       0
B1:C4     1     0       0       0       0       0       0
B1:C5     0     1       0       0       0       0       0
```

so this contrast is marginal to all other terms in the model.
Because the `car::Anova` Type II test for `B:C` is equivalent to the Type I test we can see that this contrast can be expressed as:

```
show_tests(anova(m1, type=1), fractions = TRUE)$`B:C`
      (Intercept) A     B1    C1    C2    C3    C4    C5    A:B1  A:C1  A:C2  A:C3 
B1:C1     0           0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
B1:C2     0           0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
B1:C3     0           0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
B1:C4     0           0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
B1:C5     0           0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
      A:C4  A:C5  B1:C1 B1:C2 B1:C3 B1:C4 B1:C5 A:B1:C1 A:B1:C2 A:B1:C3 A:B1:C4 A:B1:C5
B1:C1     0     0     1   1/2   1/2   1/2   1/2 60/13   30/13   30/13   30/13   30/13  
B1:C2     0     0     0     1   1/3   1/3   1/3     0   60/13   20/13   20/13   20/13  
B1:C3     0     0     0     0     1   1/4   1/4     0       0   60/13   15/13   15/13  
B1:C4     0     0     0     0     0     1   1/5     0       0       0   60/13   12/13  
B1:C5     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0       0       0       0   60/13
```

which is not marginal to the 3-way interaction term.

Comment: Thanks for your response, and for your work on the lmerTest package, I've found it very helpful! Though I now realize I didn't understand what it was doing as well as I thought. Looking forward to reading this, and the other resources you suggest, more closely.

Comment: Do you know any resources for understanding why SAS does this for Type II, and what the intuition is for what it's actually testing? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is because `A` is not centered around zero. Not sure yet why this matters though, or if it should (it doesn't seem that it should...); other answers which explore this more fully are most welcome.

```
d$Ac <- d$A - mean(d$A)
m2 <- lmer(Y ~ Ac*B*C + (1|ID), data=d)

anova(m2, type=1)
#> Type I Analysis of Variance Table with Satterthwaite's method
#>         Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF DenDF F value    Pr(>F)    
#> Ac       8.794   8.794     1    11  2.9075   0.11621    
#> B      136.641 136.641     1   121 45.1784 6.269e-10 ***
#> C       14.128   2.826     5   121  0.9343   0.46141    
#> Ac:B     0.381   0.381     1   121  0.1259   0.72330    
#> Ac:C    45.874   9.175     5   121  3.0335   0.01291 *  
#> B:C     34.821   6.964     5   121  2.3026   0.04882 *  
#> Ac:B:C  21.860   4.372     5   121  1.4456   0.21285    

anova(m2, type=2)
#> Type II Analysis of Variance Table with Satterthwaite's method
#>         Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF DenDF F value    Pr(>F)    
#> Ac       8.794   8.794     1    11  2.9075   0.11621    
#> B      136.641 136.641     1   121 45.1784 6.269e-10 ***
#> C       14.128   2.826     5   121  0.9343   0.46141    
#> Ac:B     0.381   0.381     1   121  0.1259   0.72330    
#> Ac:C    45.874   9.175     5   121  3.0335   0.01291 *  
#> B:C     34.821   6.964     5   121  2.3026   0.04882 *  
#> Ac:B:C  21.860   4.372     5   121  1.4456   0.21285    

anova(m2, type=3)
#> Type III Analysis of Variance Table with Satterthwaite's method
#>         Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF DenDF F value    Pr(>F)    
#> Ac       8.794   8.794     1    11  2.9075   0.11621    
#> B      136.641 136.641     1   121 45.1784 6.269e-10 ***
#> C       14.128   2.826     5   121  0.9343   0.46141    
#> Ac:B     0.381   0.381     1   121  0.1259   0.72330    
#> Ac:C    45.874   9.175     5   121  3.0335   0.01291 *  
#> B:C     34.821   6.964     5   121  2.3026   0.04882 *  
#> Ac:B:C  21.860   4.372     5   121  1.4456   0.21285
```

Comment: Hmm, all three tables here seem to be identical! How can this be? No difference between Type I/II/III at all?

Comment: B and C are categorical and are balanced.